# Javascript date behaving differrently

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, date

I am executing the following in chrome developers console,

```
var d = new Date("2010-03-20"); d
Fri Mar 19 2010 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)
var d = new Date("2010/03/20"); d
Sat Mar 20 2010 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)
var d = new Date("2010-3-20"); d
Sat Mar 20 2010 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)
var d = new Date("2010.3.20"); d
Sat Mar 20 2010 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)
var d = new Date("2010.03.20"); d
Sat Mar 20 2010 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)
```

My question is why is it behaving differently for "2010-03-20" where it is giving Mar 19 ?

If I do getUTCDate(), I am getting 20, but why is it different only for 2010-03-20. Is it an active bug in javascript date ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a bug, it's awkward but [intended](http://blog.dygraphs.com/2012/03/javascript-and-dates-what-mess.html)

The quick answer is that `new Date("2010-03-20")` is interpreted as a ISO-8601 date that, by default, is expressed in UTC (no timezone).

Any other date string that don't fit the `YYYY-mm-dd` format ('.' instead of '-', '3' instead of '03') is read with the current client timezone information.

And on top of that `Date.prototype.toString()` prints the date-time based on the client timezone.

Comment: Yes, it is awkward indeed!